# Bad statistics, what can we do?

Tags: discussion

I just saw the current statistics and to be honest, they are very poor. I noticed there were few questions, and this means few people that keep coming back to the site, and this means few visits from Google searches. What can we do to help  the situation?

(October 14th)

[image: Statistics Linguistics Stackexchange site, October 14th]