# Upvotes on Questions, Answers, Comments, etc

Tags: discussion

Might just be me, but why does it seem like no one is voting on questions and answers on Linguistics.SE - I'd run some queries to attempt to prove this, but beta sites are not listed on the [Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: what do you mean? The questions and answers are getting upvotes

Comment: I agree with @blunders - compared with other Stack Exchange sites I've used there is a lot less voting and also accepting of answers on this site. I noticed it weeks ago in fact.

Answer (score 3):

I vote -- though I'll admit I vote more on answers than on questions.

I've been assuming that an upvote on a question means something like "Oh hey I was wondering the same thing!"  (I'm not terribly familiar with SE outside of this subsite.)  When else would upvoting a question be appropriate?

Comment: +1 @Dan Velleman: Makes sense, though at this point it's unclear what is a "good" question - but that's a completely different question.

Comment: so here's an example of what I mean, you [agreed with Joe's comment here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/810/languages-dialects/812#812), but did not up vote it. It's very important based on my understanding to vote as often as possible. While this very well not be a pattern, it is an example of what I'm talking about in general; voting patterns are hard to see, but it still "seems" like there's a pattern to me.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm used to the way Metafilter handles this stuff, where nobody would bat an eye if I commented to say "I agree with so-and-so" but didn't give so-and-so's comment a "favorite" (which is what they use instead of upvotes).  Is that a faux pas here?

Comment: ...in fact, I went to upvote Joe's comment there and found that I couldn't.  So I'm wondering if something else is up.

Comment: In my opinion, it doesn't matter what is the norm on Metafilter or SE (hahaha)... point is if someone mainly most comments (and not questions and answers) and people agree with them, but never upvote them, they will not get a rep on the site. Votes are the core of filtering content on SE.

Comment: As for not being able to upvote a comment, only thing I'm able to think of is you're weren't logged in (unlikely, but possible) or you should try refreshing the page; which has done the trick for me in the past.

Comment: Right, the reload helped.  Never mind.

Comment: One last point, voting is free, there's no cost to voting, and if done correctly ever single vote adds value to the site. On the other hand, downvoting is a bad habit to get in, and cost rep points.

Comment: @blunders down-voting a question is free as well. Down-voting an answer is not. If you want to know what the up-votes and down-votes literally mean, put the mouse over the "arrows", you'll get a quick explanation, although you can vote for other reasons too, of course.

Comment: +1 Alenanno: Interesting, learn something new every day, here's the SE reference to what you're talking about: [FAQ-Reputation](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)

Comment: Re: Comments Upvoting... One thing I did see, which I find interesting is that the rollover text is phrased different between the **questions** (shows research effort; useful and clear), **answers** (useful), and **comments** (great). Using the word "great" seems off or subjective to me, seems like it should be "useful" too; but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Consider those as rough guidelines... Obviously you can up-vote a comment also if it's "useful" and not just "great". :)

Comment: Voting up a question can mean "This question is welcome on this site" or "This is a reasonably formulated on-topic question". Basically, voting is for encouraging welcome behaviour, so why be stingy when you want more questions on this site?

Answer (score 2):

- on stackexchange, you can vote up or down on questions and just up on comments.
- Rep is calculated using rules to encourage certian kinds of voting:

  - voting down on anything is -1 pt for you the voter (upvoting is better in comparison, and it discourages retaliatory voting).
  - voting is free for questions -and- answers (both are encouraged).
  - a voting greater than 1 to 4 ratio questions to answers for 600 votes on questions, is encouraged by a **gold** badge, [Electorate](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/badges/44/electorate).
- SE sites only get a place on data.SE [only if they are out of beta](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq).
- sometimes there are weird fluctuations in question or answer quality or just traffic altogether. [Or people might be losing interest](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186/bad-statistics-what-can-we-do).